# rename tif files sequentially

Tags: rename, filenames

I am trying to run the following command to sequentially rename image files starting with `001`. When I run the command I get the error

```
No such file or directory
```

What do I need to change in my script to get it to run?

```
echo "Enter the file path"
    read path
cd $path
num=0
for file in *.tif; do
    num=$((num+1))
    mv  "$file" "$(printf "%03d%s.tif" "$i")"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest few edits in the script,

1. Reason for error "No such file or directory" , This for loop is not actually looping through all files, but it just looping through one value `*.tif`. change the line as below.

   `for file in $(ls *.tif); do`
2. The Move command need to be edited to rename the file, change as below. (note : *${file%.*} -> This will cut out the extension and get only file name)

   `mv "$file" "$(printf "${file%.*}""%03d%s.tif" "$num")"`

The final script would look like this this.

```
echo "Enter the file path"
read path

cd $path
num=0
for file in $(ls *.tif); do
    num=$((num+1))
    mv "$file" "$(printf "${file%.*}""%03d%s.tif" "$num")"
done
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: can you paste me the exact error you are getting , whole line ?

Comment: this is the error I am getting ls: *.tif: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the directory you give as input, does it have `.tif` files ??  by the way, are you sure about this extension `.tif` , its `.tiff` ( with two `f`s) right ?.  because this is just a warning when we use ls, and file doesn't exist.

Comment: what do I need to add to get this part of the command     mv "$file" "$(printf "${file%.*}""%03d%s.tif" "$num")" ;
to run in a variable location. $path

Comment: You mean you want to move the files to different location after renaming ? If yes you can add `${path}/` before $(print without space.